# Может ли соответствующая стандарту программа быть непереносимой?

Tags: c

Если скомпилировать код с флагами

> -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11

без ошибок и предупреждений, то может ли быть непереносимой для других систем и платформ программа? Если да, то куда копать в этом случае, чтобы обеспечить её переносимость?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior

Comment: Ну, попробуйте скомпилировать программу, поведение которой может меняться в зависимости от конкретной реализации, и посмотрите, выдаются какие-либо предупреждения или нет. Например, код `int x = 30000; x *= 2; printf("%d", x);` приведёт к знаковому переполнению, если тип `int` 16-битный. Условие `if (pow(5, 2) == 25.0) printf("true");` не всегда истинно, т.к. функция `pow` не обязана возвращать математически точный результат.  Код `#include <stdint.h> ... uint8_t x;` зависит от наличия опционального типа `uint8_t`, и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа может быть не переносима если она использует опциональные расширения компилятора, такие как VLA, или использовать какие-то системно-специфические API. Собственно на голом С мало что сделаешь.

Comment: В C++ на VLA и другие расширения `-pedantic` должен давать диагностику, а в C VLA должен быть переносимым, т.к. есть в стандарте.

Comment: @tocic, начиная с C11 поддержка VLA является опциональной.

Comment: @wololo с C23 только автоматические VLA являются опциональными. Но они всё равно являются переносимыми в C в том плане, что компилятор обязан предоставить макрос, документирующий их наличие, а значит пользовательский код может "стандартным образом" быть переносимым. Но пользователь может использовать переносимые стандартные конструкции непереносимым образом (не проверяя этот макрос), да. Код же, зависящий от *unspecified* поведения, например, является непереносимым "стандартным образом" в любом случае, т.к. стандарт допускает существование не документирующей такое поведение реализации.